# User systemd unit cannot find system docker.service

Tags: systemd

I am trying to launch some docker containers under ubuntu 22.04 using a systemd user service. Since the docker containers need the docker daemon running, I include the `Requires=docker.service` in the unit file. When I try to start the docker containers, however, systemd/systemctl cannot find the docker service even though it is running.

Here is the result of the command to start the services:

```
$ systemctl --user start test-example-org
Failed to start test-example-org.service: Unit docker.service not found.
```

I can see the docker service is running using this command:

```
$ systemctl list-units --type=service | egrep 'UNIT|docker|test'
  UNIT                                                  LOAD   ACTIVE SUB     DESCRIPTION
  docker.service                                        loaded active running Docker Application Container Engine
```

I can see my user test service using a similar command:

```
$ systemctl --user  list-units --type=service | egrep 'UNIT|docker|test'
  UNIT                            LOAD   ACTIVE SUB     DESCRIPTION
● test-example-org.service loaded failed failed  The Test example.org web server
```

I can also get the status of the docker daemon as follows:

```
$ systemctl status docker
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2023-10-03 18:13:52 UTC; 2 weeks 0 days ago
TriggeredBy: ● docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.docker.com
```

My user unit file contains:

```
$ cat ~/.config/systemd/user/test-example-org.service 
[Unit]
Description=The Test example.org web server
After=multi-user.target 
Requires=docker.service 
Documentation=https://github.com/example/example

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
WorkingDirectory=%h/test-repo
Environment=TEST_WEBSITE_STARTED_BY_SYSTEMD=true
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker compose up -d
ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker compose down
Restart=on-abort

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I installed docker using `apt` (not `snap`), in case that is relevant. If I remove the `Requires=docker.service` line from the unit service file, the `systemctl --start` command does try to run the `docker compose up` command.

Why does `systemctl --user` fail to find the running docker service?

Comment: This seems to be by design - see for example [Systemd user unit that depends on system unit (sleep.target)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147904/systemd-user-unit-that-depends-on-system-unit-sleep-target)

Comment: Thanks @steeldriver. I thought I read somewhere that user services could be dependent on system services.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @steeldriver, it appears that user services are not able to require a system service to be running.

I think I have found a better way to express the dependency relationship for a user service on the docker (system) service. Instead of having

`Requires=docker.service` or `Requisite=docker.service`

in the `[Unit]` section, it's better for my service to be dependent on the presence of the docker socket.  That means adding the line

`ConditionPathExists=/var/run/docker.sock`

to the `[Service]` section. That line requires the docker socket to have been created before starting the user service. When the user service accesses the socket, the docker daemon is started if it isn't running already. Now my unit file contains:

```
$ cat ~/.config/systemd/user/test-example-org.service
[Unit]
Description=The Test example.org web server
After=multi-user.target 
Documentation=https://github.com/example/example

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ConditionPathExists=/var/run/docker.sock
WorkingDirectory=%h/test-repo
Environment=TEST_WEBSITE_STARTED_BY_SYSTEMD=true
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker compose up -d
ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker compose down
Restart=on-abort

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Now I just have to figure out why there is a permission issue connecting to the docker socket...